# Random freezes and boot issues with new MSI P67A-GD65

Tags: computer-building

I'm trying to put together my new build, which consists of the MSI P67A-GD65, 16GB Crucial DDR3 PC3-16000 RAM, Intel i7 2600K and Crucial M4 256GB SSD

My previous hardware that I'm reusing includes a couple HDDs, 2 of which are in RAID 0, and a 750W PSU.

Since the first boot, the blue light on the motherboard has been blinking on and off, which according to the manual, means that the primary BIOS failed. This continued after I updated the BIOS using MSI's LiveUpdate utility.

I've had Windows 7 up and running both as a new installation on the SSD, as well as my existing installation on the RAID 0 spindles. I've had issues with both installations where the system would just freeze - keyboard/mouse would stop responding, anything happening on the screen would freeze. I would wait a few minutes, then hard reset.

I've also had instances where the system would fail to POST. It seemed like having certain USB devices plugged into certain USB ports would influence this (specifically a USB DVD-R drive and an external hard disk). Additionally, I have not seen a single successful post with *anything* connected to the Marvell SATA controller.

It sounds to me like the motherboard may need to be RMA'd, but is it possible that anything else from my system is causing these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,

I believe you are correct the MB should be RMA'd.  I would boot into BIOS and let the machine sit.  I bet it would hang and freeze in there as well.

I expect that since the SATA controller does not allow a post that you have static damage or bad contacts on the board.

Comment: Followup: I RMA'd (and replaced) the motherboard, no more issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the Crucial M4 SSD drives on certian systems. The issue isnt common place, yet it does exist.

Verify your firmware version. If out of date consider updating to the latest firmware. Ver. 0009 was just released yesterday, give that a shot.

http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx

You could also try a registry fix. Save the blow image to notepad, then save the file under the *.reg extension and execute it, then reboot.

**Copy everything below this line**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port0]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port1]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port2]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port3]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port4]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\iaStor\Parameters\Port5]

"LPM"=dword:00000000
"LPMDSTATE"=dword:00000000
"DIPM"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already returned the original MB, but I've got a replacement sitting here waiting for me to install it. I'll definitely look into this if I have the same problems.

Can you link to any more info on the issue?

Comment: Other thing to note though is that registry hacks obviously wouldn't have any effect on the failing BIOS thing.